# How to hide add to cart button from product page of a specific product?

Tags: addtocart

Magento version 1.7.0.2

I am looking for a solution to hide add to cart button from product page? I got this hide price plugin from amasty but it hides the button only from shop page and not from the product page. I am able to hide the button sitewide by commenting out functions from view.phtml but that is not what I want.

I also tried [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3689/how-to-disable-add-to-cart-on-specific-products-and-instead-display-view-det) but didn't work for me. I am not so good at writing php functions. Can anyone help me what functions do I put and in which file so that I am able to hide add to cart button from the product page of specific products.