# Disable price & Add to cart button for particular category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart, category-products, pricing

I want to disable the price and add to cart button for particular product or a category. Instead I need to place a button that takes me to a web form page. Is there any extension that provides this functionality? Or any code tweaks?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this

[How to disable "Add to Cart" on specific products, and instead display "View Details" button in category list view?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3689/how-to-disable-add-to-cart-on-specific-products-and-instead-display-view-det)

To disable price and add to cart buttons on specific products.